# What is the difference between the sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative-constructions

I'm wondering the difference in meaning between these sentences. Or do they have the same meaning? Please explain to me.

> 1. Jurong Bird Park is larger than any other bird park in Southeast Asia.
> 2. No other bird park in Southeast Asia is as large as Jurong Bird Park.
> 3. No bird park in Southeast Asia is as large as Jurong Bird Park.
> 4. There is no other bird park in Southeast Asia as large as Jurong Bird Park.
> 5. There is no bird park in Southeast Asia as large as Jurong Bird Park.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that all 5 sentences mean the same thing. They emphasize how Jurong Bird Park is the largest in SE Asia, they sound different because of the approach. That's how diverse English can be.
Hope it help. If it answered your question mark as answered and upvote.

Comment: Pedantically, 3. and 5. entail that Jurong Bird Park lies outside Southeast Asia, as it must be as large as itself.